# Unconditional mean from conditional distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

Consider the conditional distribution
$$f(y|x)=\frac1{(a+b*x)}e^\frac{-y}{a+b*x},  (y\geq0,0\leq x\leq1)$$

Show that the conditional mean E[Y|X] is equal to $a+b*x$. [Done]

Let X in $f(y|x)$ be uniformly distributed between 0 and 1, determine the unconditional mean E[Y].

Idea so far: $f(x)=1$ for $0\leq x \leq1$, $0$ otherwise
$$f(x,y)=f(y|x)*f(x)$$
Hence:$$f(x,y)=f(y|x)=\frac1{(a+b*x)}e^\frac{-y}{a+b*x}$$
To find E[Y] I need $f(y)$, the marginal distribution of y. 
$$f(y)=\int_0^1\frac1{(a+b*x)}e^\frac{-y}{a+b*x}dx$$
However, I cannot solve this integral and therefore have to assume my reasoning is wrong. Any ideas on how to solve this example?

Comment: Hint: $E[Y\mid X]$ is a _function_ of $X$, in fact, it is $a+bX$ in this instance. The _expectation_ of this function $E[E[Y\mid X]]$ happens to equal $E[Y]$. This is called the _law of iterated expectation._  So, given the density of $X$, can you find $E[a+bX]$?

Comment: This is actually so simple, thank you very much! I was just completely determined I had to find the marginal distribution of Y first..